# Is there a metric on $\Bbb R$ based upon this measure of how close to odd and even a number is?

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose a valuation $v(x)$ on $\Bbb N_{>0}$ assigns $1$ if $x$ is even and $-1$ if $x$ is odd.

Let $v_2(x)$ be some natural or obvious extension of this valuation that continuously measures oddness vs evenness.

> Is there a continuous extension of this valuation on $\Bbb R$ that generates a metric space either on $(\Bbb R,d)$, or $(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z,d)$?

---

Background, and my thoughts on the problem:

The motivation is Collatz-related.

My attempts:

A. I can come up with various continuous extensions of the valuation.  Something like $v(x)=4(\lfloor x/2\rfloor-x/2)+1$, assigns a real number in the interval $[-1,1)$.

I was originally thinking of simply $d(x,y)=\lvert v(x)-v(y)\rvert$

But now I think $d(x,y)=\lvert v(x-y)+1\rvert$ yields a metric space on $\Bbb R/2\Bbb Z$

---

B. For a full metric space on $\Bbb R$ my thoughts so far are: $v_2=\frac{v_1+1}2$ assigns a valuation in $[0,1]$

But I'm not sure how to make a metric space.  It would seem:

$d(x,0)=\frac1{v_2}$ has a good chance but I'm struggling to consider how to treat numbers differing by an odd number, whose valuation would be infinite. A possible solution would seem to be to set their distance to zero $0$, but then the metric space would set all odd numbers equal.

---

C. Another option is a generalisation such as $v_2(x)=\sin^2\frac{\pi\cdot x}2$ which gives a continuous valuation for $x\in \Bbb [0,1]$ with the possible advantage of being differentiable throughout $\Bbb R$, but again, I don't know how (or whether there's a way) to translate the valuation into a metric which would make $\Bbb R$ a metric space.

Comment: What do you mean with the extension generating $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z,d$?

Comment: @Wojowu I mean the valuation naturally translates into a metric $d$ such that the given set is a metric space.

Comment: It seems that an extension must include the original space.  So, if anything, it should be $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I don't have setminus, I have a quotient. I did this only because it was the best I can do because every odd integer has the same valuation but a metric space on all of $\Bbb R$ would also be of interest.

Comment: The term "valuation" has a precise meaning in algebra and number theory. Or actually, unfortunately, two: "additive" vs. "multiplicative" valuations. One of the first beginners' tasks is to learn to switch between those two. -- Your $v$, however, violates at least one condition for **either possible meaning**, hence should not be called a valuation. It's just some function. Further, it is totally unclear how the metric is supposed to be related to that function $v$, hence what you are asking.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg ok thanks. I'll check the definition and see if any of the proposed variants such as $v_2$ violate the meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Given a function $v$, the two-variable function $d(x,y) = |v(x)-v(y)|$ can't possibly be a metric unless $v$ is injective (since otherwise there will be distinct points at "distance" $0$ from each other). Since you want $v$ to take the same value on all integers of a given parity, no extension of this function can yield a metric under your definition.

Comment: You mean no metric on $\Bbb R$? But it's possible on $\Bbb R/2\Bbb Z$, right?

Comment: @Dog_69 I was interested in all of $\Bbb R$ but I couldn't make that work, then I thought a compromise would be $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, then what I worked out as a possible answer to my own question looks like it works for $\Bbb R/2\Bbb Z$

Comment: The 2-adic valuation doesn't inject, but that yields a metric space with no distinct points at distance $0$ from each other.

Comment: @user334732: Of course the $2$-adic metric is not induced by the $2$-adic valuation $v_2$ via $d(x,y) \stackrel{?}= \vert v_2(x)-v_2(y)\vert$, but via $d(x,y)=2^{-v_2(x-y)}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg yes, I already know that. I don't disagree with the first sentence in this answer. This question asks if a similar thing can be done with the valuation I give. Site policy requires me to give my own thoughts. I say in the question my own thoughts fail. This answer and your comment confirm my thoughts fail, but not that the question itself is impossible. My term 'extension' is vague and this answer interprets it more restrictively than I intended. My intended meaning would permit the kind of valuation to metric relationship you have described.

Comment: @user334732 Like many words in English, "extension" has a technical meaning in math (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Restriction_and_extension ). If you didn't intend that meaning, you'll have to clarify in your question or use a different word.